# Screen Area Close

Tags: python

Does screen area close work only for area.type, but not area.ui_type?

```
bpy.ops.screen.area_close({"area": area})
```

I run into an `AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute "areas"` whenever attempting this with a ui_type,

Comment: I would have to see the code you use to set `area`, the full traceback of the error and a screenshot of the screen layout because that line is probably not generating your error.